# Yii Framework: Pagation Callback Method

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, clistview

I have a CListView on a page and every time i navigate to page 2 or any other page I want to call a method that formats the view. But it do not seem to work every time I navigate to another page.

The Javascript method I want to call is called `updateDivs()`

Here is my list view widget

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                                    'itemView' => '_customview',
                                    'id' => 'bannerslist',
                                    'ajaxUpdate' => true,
                                    'afterAjaxUpdate' => ' updateDivs()',
                                    'enablePagination' => true,
                                    'itemsCssClass' => 'row banners-list',
                                    'summaryText' => 'Total ' . $pages->itemCount . ' Results Found',
                                    'pager' => array(
                                        'header' => '',
                                        'prevPageLabel' => '<',
                                        'nextPageLabel' => '>',
                                    ),
                                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to test, it should works well.

`'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(id,data){alert("test");}'`

So if this code will works perfect then you should search problem in your `updateDivs()` function

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, you missed to write `js:function(id, data)` which is significant to call a method.

You can use as follows :

```
'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id, data) {updateDivs();}',
```

Look here for [more info](http://yiiapi.com/CListView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail).